# is it possible for a two divergent series have a convergant diffrence?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a series where I have split it into 2.
the first is the sum of a sequence $a_n$ that converge to $1/2$. and the second $b_n$ is the same thing. is it possible for their difference $\sum{a_n - b_n}$ to converge?
the original question is does this series converge : $1$ - $3/4$ + $4/6$ - $5/8$ + $6/10$ - $7/12$ + $\dots$
this is what I wrote tell me if it is true or did I make a mistake somewhere:

we can rewrite this as 1 - $3/4$ + $2/3$ - $5/8$ + $3/5$ - $7/12$ + $4/7$ - $\dots$\
now let $(a_n)$ = $1$ , $2/3$ , $3/5$ , $4/7$, $\dots$, this is a decreasing sequence represented as $(a_n)$ = $\{\frac{n}{2n-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which converge to $1/2$

and let $(b_n)$ = $3/4$ , $5/8$ , $7/12$ , $\dots$ = $\{\frac{2n+1}{4n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $b_n$ also converge to $1/2$

so since $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges to the same thing then $a_n$ - $b_n$ should converge to zero by ALT (algebraic limit theorem). now for $\sum{a_n - b_n}$ pick $N > 0$ big enough so that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty{a_n - b_n}$ converge to 0. thus since it tail converges so is the series.

I feel i may have to rewrite it especially the last part.

Comment: If you take $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = 1/n + 1/n^2$ they'll both diverge but their difference will converge.  But anyway your original series can't converge because the terms don't go to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $a_n-b_n$ converges to 0 isn't enough for the convergence of the series ($\frac{1}{n}$ for example).
But there holds $a_n-b_n=\frac{1}{8n^2-4n}$ and you get absolute convergence of the series easily by a comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.
One thing, don't split the sequence in $a_n,b_n$, it doesn't help, it just causes confusion in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for a two divergent series have a convergent difference?

The answer is yes.

One may consider
$$
S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\left( \frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right), \quad T_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n,
$$ We have 
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}S_N=\infty, \quad \lim_{N \to \infty}T_N=\infty
$$ and, as $N \to \infty$,
$$
S_N-T_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2} \to \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider for a counterexample: $a_n = b_n =1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Your series is:

$$\sum_{n \ge 1}\left( \frac{n}{2n -1} - \frac{2n + 1}{4n} \right) = \frac14 \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac1{n(2n-1)}$$

Now use the comparison test to conclude.